# Capturing date and time between square brackets in PHP using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, datetime, preg-match

I need some way of capturing date and time between square brackets. So for the following string:

```
$str= '10.1.1.107 - - [27/Oct/2016:06:40:58 +0000] "GET /advise/asi/3571502300/sky/2/con/113 HTTP/1.1"';
```

I'm tring to get `advise` and `con` as follows:

```
preg_match("/advise\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/sky\/2\/.*con\/([0-9]+)/", $str, $matches);
```

The function returns the following `$matches`:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => 
  array(2) {
   [0]=>
    "3571502300"
   [1]=>
    "113"
 }
)
```

Then I want to get date and time between square brackets, I have the following regular expression:

```
/\[([0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]\/Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec\/20\d\d:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+0000)]\]\/advise\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/sky\/2\/.* con\/([0-9]+)/
```

But it [captures nothing](https://regex101.com/r/ykuAP9/2)

Is my regular expression wrong?

I get an array like this:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => 
  array(3) {
   [0]=>
    27/Oct/2016:06:40:58 +0000 
   [1]=>
    "3571502300"
   [2]=> 
    "113"
 }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$re = '/\[(?P<dt>\d\d\/[A-Z][a-z]{2}\/\d{4}(?:\:\d\d){3} \+\d{4})\] ' .
  '"[A-Z]{3,4} \/advise\/asi\/(?P<asi>\d+)\/sky\/\d+\/con\/(?P<con>\d+)/';

preg_match($re, $str, $m);
var_dump($m['dt'], $m['asi'], $m['con']);
// or, if your prefer numeric indices:
//var_dump($m[1], $m[2], $m[3]);
```

*Output*

```
string(26) "27/Oct/2016:06:40:58 +0000"
string(10) "3571502300"
string(3) "113"
```

**Description**

The values are captured using named [subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) in the form:

```
(?P<name>pattern)
```

where `name` is the key name in the matches array.

`(?:\:\d\d){3}` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) for the part after the year (in particular, `:06:40:58`).

The rest is simple.

**Errors in your Regular Expression**

Note that in the sample code above the square brackets are escaped with a backslash: `\[`, `\]`, since in regular expressions they mean a [set of characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). You didn't escape the square brackets, so the characters between are interpreted as a set of characters.

The part `sky\/2\/.* con\/` is wrong because the original string doesn't contain spaces before `con/`.

You have hard-coded the timezone offset (`\+0000`). Although it is unlikely that the timezone will change on your host, it still is possible. So it is better to write it in a more genetic form, e.g. `\+\d{4}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your alternative versions, otherwise the `or` affects the whole regex.

For example:

```
^12|34$
```

Allows `12` or `34` but

```
^1(2|3)4$
```

Allows `124` or `134`.

Your string also has a space between the timezone offset and the seconds so you need to add that literally (or you could use the `\h` metacharacter).

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ykuAP9/3

So the regex should be:

```
~\[((?:[0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)/20\d\d:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+0000)\]~
```